# Django programming Training Course

Tags: django

I would like to know if anybody in here knows some excellent opportunities to learn Django web programming in an e.g. intense 2 week programming course. Anywhere on the world. Preferably in the Bay area. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for the time!

Comment: MacPython: I'm in the Bay Area and might be able to help you out. Msg me on my gmail (use StackOverflow username)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your after a course that is a week or so long check out [here](http://www.bignerdranch.com/classes/django). A friend of mine did the cocoa course and highly recommends it. It is a bit pricy at $3500 but all the reviews i've read have raved about it being so good.

Answer (score 12):

I for one learned by doing - I followed [the tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/), and then I built something useful.

When I got stuck, I looked at the excellent [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/), and when I got really stuck, I asked here on Stack Overflow (where I might add, I managed to learn a lot more by [answering questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:20972+django) about Django).

All this excellent training cost me the princely sum of $0.00.

Comment: Yes me as well. But i would like to have a course that in a short time gives me all the best tools to work with django.

Answer (score 3):

There are some training courses listed here:

http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoTraining

---

Free resources to train yourself at your own pace :)

http://docs.djangoproject.com/ and http://www.djangobook.com/

Answer (score 2):

This is a shorter course than you had in mind, but in case others find it useful, Caktus Group has begun hosting a Django Fundamentals Bootcamp 2-day weekend course.  More details can be found here:

http://www.caktusgroup.com/events/details/django-fundamentals-bootcamp/

Pricing is cheaper than the course listed above at $400 early-bird and $550 regular.